# Create a id(key) baed on JSON document for Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

At my Java application I need to store a JSON document at ElasticSearch. I want to prevent a duplication of the documents in ES so I'm going to calculate some kind of id(key) based on JSON object/string and use it as own id for this document when indexing at ES. Unfortunately I don't have any candidates for a natural key inside of this JSON, so should take into account the whole JSON object/string for this key generation.

This is an example of JSON document:

```
{
   "filterQueries":[
      {
         "type":"LessOrEqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":630,
         "value":799621200000,
         "operator":"<="
      }
   ],
   "sortCriteriaIds":[
      566,
      572
   ],
   "sortWeightCriteriaDirection":"DESC",
   "sortTotalVotesCriteriaDirection":null,
   "sortCriteriaCoefficients":{
      "572":20.0
   },
   "sortCharacteristicId":631,
   "sortCharacteristicDirection":"DESC",
   "sortDecisionPropertyName":"createDate",
   "sortDecisionPropertyDirection":"DESC",
   "excludeChildDecisionIds":null,
   "includeChildDecisionIds":null,
   "pageNumber":0,
   "pageSize":100
}
```

What is the best way to calculate this key based on JSON object/string in Java ? Performance is a very important criterion to me there.

Comment: If the json will be the same, but properties key order is non-consistent, should the resulting key be the same?

Comment: Ideally yes, but not mandatory. I'll try to keep the order by myself

Comment: then you can simply stringify and then sha256(string)? Or smaller size any hash... depending on hash size the collision probability will be different.

Comment: I have even seen that telegram's MPROTO using CRC32 for sigining operations. But the collision could be too high. (For them it is working)

Comment: Thanks, I have to check the speed of sha256 for such kind of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed concerns very much. You can use XOR operation (almost CRC32 for any size).

Pseudocode:

```
input_string = Stringify(json)
result = 0;
for(each chunk of size K from input_string){
    result = result XOR chunk;
}
return result
```

Comment: I think crc32 should work for me, thanks !  `public static long crc32(String input) {
  byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
  Checksum checksum = new CRC32();
  checksum.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

  return checksum.getValue();
 }`